# Getting error code 0 when requesting to roblox login api v2

Tags: javascript, node.js, roblox

I am getting a weird error while requesting to Roblox Login API

**Request URL:**
`https://auth.roblox.com/v2/login`

**Request Body:**

```json
{ ctype: 'Username', cvalue: 'USERNAME', password: 'PASSWORD' }
```

**Request Headers:**

```json
{ 'content-type': 'application/json', 'x-csrf-token': 'X_CSRF_TOKEN', accept: 'application/json' }
```

And then I get this response body:

**Response Body:**

```json
{ code: 0, message: 'Challenge is required to authorize the request' }
```

Note: Sometimes this works and I am asked for a 2 Factor Authentication code, and then I am able to login through this successfully.

I need to know why I get this error, because sometimes I am asked for a 2 Factor Authentication code, and then I am able to login through this successfully.

Comment: The challenge is usually a captcha with a secret that only the Roblox apps know. You may be stuck.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to login (via roblox website or api), you will most likely get prompted with a **captcha** to complete which the challenge. You can get more details on the **captcha** by looking at the headers of the response.